# Joomla Override: can't seem to find upmost container

Tags: html, css, joomla

I want to override the **Login module**. I have created the override in the html folder, but I can't seem to find the upmost `div` with `class="login"` that is visible when viewing the original Login module with Firebug. I have searched all files in mod_login.

I want to place the following above the module:

```
<div class="item-page">
    <div class="page-header">
        <h2 itemprop="name">Login</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

*Thanks in advance*

**EDIT:** I'm using Joomla 3.4.6. Login_Module is in it's original state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based off the limited information provided...

You should only have to place the default.php file from `/modules/mod_login/tmpl/` into `/templates/[template_name]/html/mod_login/` to override the frontend module.

To modify the module for the administrator side, you would copy `/administrator/modules/mod_loing/tmpl/default.php` to `/administrator/templates/[template_name]/html/mod_login/default.php`

If the code you're trying to edit isn't in that file, then you may want to try looking at the com_users component which has the file: `/components/com_users/views/login/tmpl/default_login.php` and see if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks. The '<div>' was in 'com_users'.